# Really strange PHP behaviour with multiple file upload, my bad?

Tags: php, forms, file, file-upload

Strange behaviour here. Current `upload_max_filesize` is `2M`. **Is there something wrong with my PHP installation?**

```
<?php if(isset($_FILES['images'])) var_dump($_FILES['images']); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="processupload.php"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="images[]" name="images[]" type="file" multiple="" />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Testing shows different behaviour:

- Big size (12M) mp3 file: `$_FILES['images']` is not setted
- Medium size (4M) mp3 file: `$_FILES['images']` exists **but** `$_FILES['images']['type']` is empty and `$_FILES['images']['size']` is empty

**EDIT**: found myself but i can't answer to my own question yet:

- In the case of 12M file `$_FILES['images']` is empty because the sum of the (size of) post data is **greater than post_max_size** ([details here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php))
- In the case of 4M file `type` and `size` are empty because upload size is **greater than upload_max_filesize**

Answer (score 0):

When having multiple upload files, you will have to access the current one with an index 0..MaxUploadFiles

```
$_FILES[<current_index_for_file>]['images']['error']
```

Comment: Not true. `$_FILES[0]['images']` is empty even with multiple files selected.

Comment: Sorry, forget about ['error'], is being setted correctly, my bad, But the strange behaviour about type and size still remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can just examine output of

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

And you will now how the array is structured. 
If I remember well, you can access values with:

```
$_FILES['images']['size'][<index>]
$_FILES['images']['type'][<index>]
$_FILES['images']...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put these lines at top of your code, because your global settings in PHP.ini is limited, you can change that by programmatic using below lines

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '25M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');
```

While you increase the size of POST datas , you have to increase script execution time also else it will throw fatal error, you can increase the script execution time by

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

here I mentioned as 0 that is unlimited, for security purpose you have to test with your server and limit it with some seconds.

Comment: Completely wrong. The script is executed AFTER the data upload. For this reason max_execution_time is useless. And post_max_size/upload_max_filesize can't be changed since data has been already uploaded. Btw correct anwser is in my first post.

Comment: @Polmonino you can have this codes as common for both the pages (form page and action page) and you should know where to place this codes think well. don't say completely wrong before analyzing anything. cool buddy..

Comment: Again, you are wrong. It doesn't matter where you put `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` because they are PHP_INI_PERDIR both (means you can't change them in scripts). And `max_execution_time` is useless because the script in executed ONLY after upload completes!